# $1 to $25 million budget

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

In the phrase "$1 to $25 million budget," I don't like how that reads in my head -- I feel as if it reads "one to twenty-five million budget." But, I know it's not really accepted to spell out "dollar" if the dollar sign is used. I can't find any strict rules, however, on how to structure a range of millions when it is a descriptor of a noun (in this case, "budget"). What I'd like to use is "$1 to $25 million-dollar budget." Or, is it "million dollar?"

I think I am getting in my own head here. Can someone please just set me straight? Thank you!

Comment: You should absolutely NOT use both the $ sign and the word 'dollar'.  If you go with the 'dollar' option, do not hyphenate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lowercase 'm' as an abbreviation for million.

- "$1m to $25m budget."
- "A budget between $1m and $25m"

Other options:

- "$1 million to $25 million budget."
- "A budget between one and twenty-five million dollars."
- "A one million to twenty-five million dollar budget."
- "A one to twenty-five million dollar budget."

It depends on your context and audience. For a technical, professional, or academic document I suggest the lower-case 'm.' For journalistic or narrative purposes you could use a more longform option.

Comment: Thank you! I very much like the first one. I appreciate all your ideas.